# Why my search function is not rerendering the component?

Tags: reactjs

I am now trying to make a search on my react component.

The data are coming from the graphql.

```
const blogs = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { fields: publishedDate, order: DESC }) {
        edges {
          node {
            title
            publishedDate
            slug
            tag
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

Here is my return state for my component.
As you can see i am rendering posts by calling a function

```
const renderBlogPosts = (someSearch) => {
    console.log(someSearch)
    if(!someSearch){
      return blogs.allContentfulBlogPost.edges.map((oneEdge, i) => {
        const tags = oneEdge.node.tag.split(" ")
        return (
          <div className="blog__post" key={`blog${i}`}>
            <Link to={oneEdge.node.slug}>
              <h4 className={`title${i}`}>{oneEdge.node.title}</h4>
              <p className="blog__date">{oneEdge.node.publishedDate}</p>
              <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                {tags.map((oneTag, i) => {
                  return <p className="blog__tag" key={`tag${i}`}>{oneTag}</p>
                })}
              </div>
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
    else{
      return <p>banana</p>
    }
  }


return (
    <Layout>
      <form onSubmit={handleSumbit}>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
        <button>Search</button>
      </form>

      <div className="blog__container">
          {renderBlogPosts()}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
```

I am now just return the `p` tag if there is something in the search result.
the search event is coming from the submit button.

```
const handleChange = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSumbit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // Trying to change start if it will help rerender
    let someRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    setRandom(someRandom);
    renderBlogPosts(search)
  }
```

From what i believe this should re render when i press the button & this `p` tag should replace the original posts with the text banana.

But the posts are not rerendering

Comment: `renderBlogPosts` is expecting the parameter `someSearch` - you are calling it without any parameter in your component return. Calling `renderBlogPosts` inside an input handler is also not going to do anything because you're just returning JSX, not rendering it.

Comment: @lawrence-witt there was a set state `[search, setSearch]` so when the user type in the input `someSearch ` should have some string. 
I am not clear about rendering part can you show me an example